# How to know in JSF 1.2 and richfaches the id from h:column in a h:datatable

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, richfaces-modal

I have a datatable from which I open with a click on an image the `<rich:modalPanel>`. But the `<rich:componentControl for="panel" attachTo="showPreview"` must have the exact id, in my case below: `showPreview`, but as my link is inside a dataTable, it will be generated like `1:showPreview` `2:showPreview`.....`n:showPreview`

Is there any way to know in which line of the table i am, to get a dynamic binding?

My XHTML in JSF 1.2 looks something like this:

```html
<h:dataTable  styleClass="tb_tabletag" id="dtContentPosts" value="#{listOfObjects}" var="object">
    <h:column id="columnnumber" >
        <h:outputLink id="showPreview" value="#">
        <h:graphicImage value="preview.png" />      
        <rich:componentControl for="panel" attachTo="showPreview" operation="show"
            event="onclick"/>
        </h:outputLink>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
...
...
...
<rich:modalPanel id="panel" autosized="true">
  some stuff 
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Check the RichFaces 3.3 live demo for `<rich:modalPanel>` and `<rich:dataTable>` example: [Edit Table with ModalPanel](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?tab=editDataTable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Luiggi for your link, with the given source code,this helped me to find my simple trick:
i get now the number with: `#{listOfObjects.indexOf(object)}`

the only important thing is, that the modalPanel is in a `<h:column></h:column>` to receive the correct number
works perfect